# java.io.IOException: Incorrect function while runing grails webapp on guest os

Tags: java, windows, grails, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have simple grails app, it works good at my system, but it is hard to share it with other people where everyone has some different settings so i thought it woudl be good to create vagrant box so everyone coudl run it on os with same settings. Ok so let get us down to the business on guest os i can run app also(app is in shared folder) but i recive errors

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Incorrect function.

at org.grails.io.watch.WatchServiceDirectoryWatcher.addWatchDirectory(WatchServiceDirectoryWatcher.java:183)
at org.grails.io.watch.WatchServiceDirectoryWatcher.addWatchDirectory(WatchServiceDirectoryWatcher.java:153)
at org.grails.io.watch.DirectoryWatcher.addWatchDirectory(DirectoryWatcher.java:111)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp.configureDirectoryWatcher(GrailsApp.groovy:299)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:210)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:174)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp.enableDevelopmentModeWatch(GrailsApp.groovy:110)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:65)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:347)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:336)
at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at baseapp.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
```

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Incorrect function.

```
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsWatchService$Poller.implRegister(WindowsWatchService.java:420)
at sun.nio.fs.AbstractPoller.processRequests(AbstractPoller.java:260)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsWatchService$Poller.run(WindowsWatchService.java:580)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I was trying to figure out what is wrong, so my only guess based on `WatchServiceDirectoryWatch.java` is that grails is trying to set some dir which it will be scanning(i dont know for what?) but because project is in shared folder grails is trying to set dir to which it does not have access(guessing). My question is what  cant i do to do not recive that errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should go deeper and look at [grails.boot.GrailsApp](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-core/src/main/groovy/grails/boot/GrailsApp.groovy#L299) `at grails.boot.GrailsApp.configureDirectoryWatcher(GrailsApp.groovy:299)` which

> Creates and returns a file change listener for notifying the plugin manager of changes.

and then `at grails.boot.GrailsApp.enableDevelopmentModeWatch(GrailsApp.groovy:110)`
which is inside a function named `enableDevelopmentModeWatch`.

Comment: Thanks for advice, so i think it only appears in development mode when grails `auto-reloading` option is up.